# Pig UDF function that gives combinations of all items in a bag?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm looking for a Pig function that from a set of values:

```
a b c d
```

would do trees:

```
a,b,c
a,b,d
a,c,d
b,c,d
```

All combinations, but with order.
Have you seen something similiar? 
Regards 
Pawel

Comment: Do you have just one bag in your input relation?

Comment: Yes, one bug but many tuples inside. Lets say there are rows: {(a,b,c,d),(m,n,o,p,r)}

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use flatten on the same bag multiple times to get all possible permutations.

```
inpt = load '....' using PigStorage(',') as (v : chararray);
bag = group inpt all;
result = foreach bag generate FLATTEN(inpt), FLATTEN(inpt), FLATTEN(inpt);
result = order result by $0, $1, $2
```